# Qt PushButton displaying image

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm having trouble finding a way to open an image in a new window on pushbutton. In my ui "calculator.ui" I have a Qpushbutton called "Open". In theory, pressing Open will link to a new window, "showmap.ui". I've made a slot in calculator called "void calculator::on_Open_clicked()" . I know I can open the new window with,

```
void calculator::on_Open_clicked()
{
    m1 = new ShowMap(this);
    m1 ->show();
}
```

however, in my showmap.ui I have a Qlabel named "map1" that I want to display an image (the map) with. I cannot refrence map1 in my on_Open_clicked() function because map1 is not a part of calculator. How would I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add an extra parameter to the ShowMap constructor, which is the map to be shown

Comment: So if I want to show the map "map1" , would the code look like ```m1 = new ShowMap(this, map1); ```? And if so, how do I show the image C:/Users/u/Desktop/c++/calculator2/map.bmp ?

Comment: @steven_h well, the implementation choices are up to you. But one option is to pass the file path of the map image as a QString.